# Make select list wider than container?

Tags: css

I have a container that has horizontal padding. Within this container is a select list that i want to be the full width of the container, as if no padding was applied. Can I do this with negative margins?

I cant remove the padding of the container as there a lots of other elements within it and for various reasons I dont want to apply margins to each of them. I cant change the HTML at all.

If I apply negative margin the select list is shifted to the left, but not widened. Im sure negative margins applied to a div within a container behave differently.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/usmqC

```
<div>
  <p>Other content up here</p>
  <p>Other content up here</p>
  <p>Other content up here</p>
  <p>Other content up here</p>

  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>

div {
  background: grey;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  1margin-left: -25px;
  margin-right: -25px;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is probably what you need:

```
div {
  background: grey;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
}

select {
  width: calc(100% + 50px);  /* 50px because padding is 25px left and 25px right*/
  margin-left: -25px;
  display: block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/efmLewLw/)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly.

**Updated your code:**

```
   div {
  background: grey;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 20%;
  margin: auto;
}

select {
  margin-left: -6%;
  width: 112%;
   display: block;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jlAnw)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can see for this is to absolutely position the select and set `left` and `right` to 0.

Using `width: 120%` and negative margins works initially but is not a responsive solution if thats what you need.

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/guyfedwards/pen/ikhbI)